# Jump to a label from inline assembly to C

Tags: c, gcc, x86, inline-assembly, goto

I have a written piece of code in assembly and at some points of it, I want to jump to a label in `C`. So I have the following code (shortened version but still, I am having the same problem):

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    #define JE asm volatile("jmp end");
    int main(){
        printf("hi\n");
        JE
        printf("Invisible\n");
        end:
        printf("Visible\n");
        return 0;
    }
```

This code compiles, but there is no `end` label in the disassembled version of the code.

If I change the label name from `end` to any other thing (let's say `l1`, both in asm code(`jmp l1`) and in the `C` code), the compiler says that

```sh
    main.c:(.text+0x6b): undefined reference to `l1'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    Makefile:2: recipe for target 'main' failed
    make: *** [main] Error 1
```

I have tried different things(different length, different cases, upper, lower, etc.) and I think it only compiles with `end` label. And with `end` label, I am receiving segmentation fault because, there is no `end` label in the disassembled version.

*Compiled with:* gcc -O0 main.c -o main

*Disassembled code:*

```
    000000000000063a <main>:
     63a:   55                      push   %rbp
     63b:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
     63e:   48 8d 3d af 00 00 00    lea    0xaf(%rip),%rdi        # 6f4 <_IO_stdin_used+0x4>
     645:   e8 c6 fe ff ff          callq  510 <puts@plt>
     64a:   e9 c9 09 20 00          jmpq   201018 <_end> # there is no _end label!
     64f:   48 8d 3d a1 00 00 00    lea    0xa1(%rip),%rdi        # 6f7 <_IO_stdin_used+0x7>
     656:   e8 b5 fe ff ff          callq  510 <puts@plt>
     65b:   48 8d 3d 9f 00 00 00    lea    0x9f(%rip),%rdi        # 701 <_IO_stdin_used+0x11>
     662:   e8 a9 fe ff ff          callq  510 <puts@plt>
     667:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
     66c:   5d                      pop    %rbp
     66d:   c3                      retq   
     66e:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
```

So, the questions are:

1. Am I doing something wrong? I have seen this kind of jumps (from
   assembly to C) in codes. I can provide example links.
2. Why the compiler/linker cannot find `l1` but can find `end`?

Comment: The compiler prepends an underscore to certain symbols. So label `end` in C will be label `_end` in assembler.

Comment: This is what `asm goto` is for.  [GCC Inline Assembly: Jump to label outside block](//stackoverflow.com/a/44886947)

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: It won't just be `_end`.  It might be something like `_main.end`, or more likely just a usual autonumbered label like `.L123:`

Comment: Then how this code works: https://github.com/IAIK/transientfail/blob/master/pocs/spectre/PHT/sa_oop/main.c

Comment: It doesn't; the `end` label that inline asm references is in the `.data` section and happens to be defined by the compiler or linker to mark the end of that section.  `asm volatile("je end")` has no connection to the C label in that function.  I commented out some of the code in other functions to get it to compile without the "cacheutils.h" header but that didn't affect that part of the `oop()` function; see https://godbolt.org/z/jabYu3

Comment: @PeterCordes That's weird. I run that code a week ago without touching anything. That's why I am puzzled. Their code can work but mine doesn't. Anyways, the `asm volatile("end:")` solved the problem for now

Comment: @kyurt7  that might work for some toy experiment with optimization disabled but  it's Undefined Behaviour and could break just by enabling optimization.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ok, I'll keep in my mind the `asm goto` stuff. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what `asm goto` is for. [GCC Inline Assembly: Jump to label outside block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744055/gcc-inline-assembly-jump-to-label-outside-block/44886947#44886947)

**Note that defining a label *inside* another asm statement will sometimes work (e.g. with optimization disabled) but IS NOT SAFE.**

```
    asm("end:");   // BROKEN; NEVER USE 
                   // except for toy experiments to look at compiler output
```

GNU C does not define the behaviour of jumping from one asm statement to another without `asm goto`.  The compiler is allowed to assume that execution comes out the end of an `asm` statement and e.g. put a store after it.

---

The C `end:` label within a given function *won't* just have the asm symbol name of `end` or `_end:` - that wouldn't make sense because separate C functions are each allowed to have their own `end:` label.  It *could* be something like `main.end` but it turns out GCC and clang just use their usual autonumbered labels like `.L123`.

> Then how this code works: https://github.com/IAIK/transientfail/blob/master/pocs/spectre/PHT/sa_oop/main.c

**It doesn't; the `end` label that `asm volatile("je end");` references is in the `.data` section and happens to be defined by the compiler or linker to mark the end of that section**.

`asm volatile("je end")` has no connection to the C label in that function.

I commented out some of the code in other functions to get it to compile without the "cacheutils.h" header but that didn't affect that part of the `oop()` function; see https://godbolt.org/z/jabYu3 for disassembly of the linked executable with JE_4k changed to JE_16 so it's not huge.  It's disassembly of a linked executable so you can see the numeric address of `je     6010f0 <_end>` while the `oop` function itself starts at 4006e0 and ends at 400750.  (So it doesn't contain the branch target).

If this happens to work for Spectre exploits, that's because apparently the branch is never actually taken.